# spring mvc form:select tag doesnot generate name attribute in html source

Tags: html, forms, spring-mvc, select, form-submit

spring form tag

```
<form:select path="gameMap" id="games">
   <form:option value="-" label="--Please Select"/>
   <form:options items="${gameMap}"/>
</form:select>
```

generates html source as

```
<select id="games">
    <option value="-">--Please Select</option>
    <option value="3">boxing</option>
    <option value="2">cricket</option>
    <option value="1">swimming</option>
    <option value="32768">game2</option>
    <option value="32769">game1</option>
</select>
```

I couldnt find name attribute in generated html source . How can I add it ? and if there is no  name than how can I handle request param on form submit ?

Comment: Even if you don't find Name on tag,just type there it will work. Don't worry about auto suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you don't find Name on tag,just type there it will work. Don't worry about auto suggestions

```
<select id="games">
    <option value="-" name="">--Please Select</option>
    <option value="3" name="">boxing</option>
</select>
```